# Start Class in Kotlin sets full Path in red

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, start-activity

So I'm trying to start a class with a onClickListener in Kotlin. The class (SelectLanguage) is in another package located under .request.booknow:

```
icTree.setOnClickListener {
            val request = Intent(this@DetailActivity, com.myapp.myapp.request.booknow.SelectLanguage)
            request.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            applicationContext.startActivity(request)
        }
```

AndroidStudio automatically fills in the whole path to the SelectLanguage-Class, but marks com. **myapp** . myapp.... in RED and says "unresolved reference: myapp"
I have no idea why this is happening, I have another onclicklistener set to a JavaClass:

```
...
val request = Intent(applicationContext, BirdsMain::class.java)
...
```

which works perfectly fine. The other one to the Kotlin Class doesn't work. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the path manually in the import section and then write your class like

```
val request = Intent(this@DetailActivity, SelectLanguage::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing the line

```
val request = Intent(this@DetailActivity, com.myapp.myapp.request.booknow.SelectLanguage)
```

with

```
val request = Intent(this@DetailActivity, SelectLanguage::class.java)
```

and let the Android Studio do the auto-import for you by `alt-enter` while having the cursor on `SelectLanguage`

Comment: That's what I tried first, it hops to the same error again :(